# Incompatible argument type on compilation

Tags: compilation, magento2

We have a custom extension that worked on mageplaza custom pdf invoice extension on magento 2.2.7.

The mageplaza module needed to be updated, so we did. Now the updated module is not compatible with the other extension that fixes the layout of magento2 attributes on the invoice...

So the two extensions that should work together are:

- FrikandelX Invoice
- Mageplaza/Pdfinvoice

Unfortunatly when we compiled magento code it throws this error:

**Errors during compilation:
FrikandelX\Invoice\Block\Invoice\Items

Incompatible argument type: Required type: 
\Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Helper\Data. Actual type: array; File:**

/xx/Xx/mage227-dev/app/code/FrikandelX/Invoice/Block/Invoice/Items.php

Total Errors Count: 1

**This is the FrikandelX file:**

### /public_html/app/code/FrikandelX/Invoice/Block/Invoice/Items.php

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Tax\Helper\Data;

class Items extends \Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Block\Invoice\Items{
    protected $_productRepository;

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Data $taxHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $taxHelper, $data);
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getProduct($sku)
{
    try {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return $product;
}

private function _getProduct($sku)
{
    try {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($sku);
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
    die;
}

public function getDiscount($item, $product, $invoice)
{
    if($item->getPrice() == $product->getPrice()){
        $discountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        if($discountAmount){

            $rowTotalDiscounted = $item->getRowTotal() - $discountAmount;
            $rowTotal = $product->getPrice() * $item->getQty();
            $item->setRowTotal($rowTotalDiscounted);


            $invoice->setSubTotal($invoice->getSubTotal() - $rowTotal + $rowTotalDiscounted);


            $invoice->setDiscountAmount(null);


            return 100 - round($rowTotalDiscounted / $rowTotal * 100, 0);
        }

        return '0';
    }

    return 100 - round($item->getPrice() / $product->getPrice() * 100, 0);
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appriciated. I hope I explained it clearly and thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when the IDE you use automatically imports the classes or interfaces that the code refers to, for example `$data`.

In this case the parameter `Data $taxHelper` that's injected into the constructor is of the wrong type as per you `use` statement:

```
use Magento\Tax\Helper\Data;
```

So you need to make sure that the `Data $taxHelper` parameter actually contains data of type:

```
Mageplaza\PdfInvoice\Helper\Data
```

Hope it helps.